# Is it possible to find a specific tree (root) in a n-ary tree in c++?

Tags: c++, if-statement, data-structures, tree

I am storing results from different subjects of different students. The root is student id, child of root is subjectid, and child of subjectid is grade. If user tries to insert a already graded subject to a student, the grade will ble replaced. If user tries to insert a new subject to a already registered student, it will make a new child (subjectid) from the root. Lastly if the student isnt registered, it will make a new tree.

I am having a hard time trying to make if statements to the statements above.

This is my code currently

```
void add_result(){

    int grade;
    int studentid;
    int testid;

    display_all_students();

    std::cout << "Enter student id:\n";
    std::cin >> studentid;

    display_all_test();

    std::cout << "Enter test id:\n";
    std::cin >> testid;

    std::cout << "Enter grade:\n";
    std::cin >> grade;

    if (int x = 0) {
        // if (studentid found && testid found)
        // function to replace the grade
    }

    if (int x = 1) {
        // if (studentid found, not testid)
        // function to make a new child in that students tree, and sett a grade
        TreeNode *root;
        root = studentid;
    }

    // else{ makes a new tree with student id as root
    TreeNode* root; // makes a new tree with a root
    root = GetNewNode(studentid); // root will be studentid
    addChild(root, testid);
    addChild(root->children[0],grade); // root->children[0] means at index 0
}
```

I tried to use map within a map where student id and subject id will be the to primary keys. However, this limits each student to only one subject since you can only have one key to a element in a map.

Comment: I'm getting a strong feeling of [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here. Searching trees for extra roots is a concept unfamiliar to me. Take a step back from trees and roots and try to explain what you would like to achieve in high level terms. And/or make a [mre] that demonstrates one specific problem you want to solve.

Comment: Where are the implementations of `TreeNode`, `GetNewNode` and `addChild`? If you want with `std:map` you need to show us your attempt with it?